# Previously Working Twins Does Not Accept My User

Tags: azure-digital-twins

I created a Twins instance and got a basic example up and running. A few days go by and I launch the Twins Explorer from my dashboard in Azure Portal. The Single Sign on lets me sign on using my Microsoft Account and upon logging in it states:

> Selected user account does not exist in tenant 'Microsoft Services' and cannot access the application '856....' in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Please use a different account.

How can I resolve this?

---

###### Successful Login After Host Popup with No Changes

As of the writing of this message, and after previous failed attempts, the Twins Dashboard (*no settings changed mind you*), on the last attempt the `Enter Host` popup was preseented to me. I was allowed to re-add my host and it worked.

Comment: Do you have multiple subscriptions? If you have multiple subscriptions, make sure you've selected the right one. You can also change the directory through Azure Portal. Once you've selected the correct tenant/directory, you can check to see if the user does exist in that directory by going to:  Azure Active Directory -> Users -> All Users -> Search for the user

Comment: 3 Subscriptions, 1 directory for 1 login. In the directory there are two users, one of which is my login which has the role of `Global Administrator` and the other which is a leftover login from OWIN SSO tests I did months ago. Where exactly do I select the **right** subscription? When I login to the Azure Portal I am presented with all three subscriptions, and there is not place to change that...

Comment: Here are the steps to Associate a subscription to a directory :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-how-subscriptions-associated-directory#associate-a-subscription-to-a-directory